# What is the name of this widgets?

Tags: themes, gtk3

I am tweaking a theme to my taste and I changed the accent color from orange to #9E9EB3. The problem is that one kind of widget now have mixed color of orange & #9E9EB3.

Can some one tell me what is the name of this kind of widgets, so I can find them in the gtk-widgets.css file and fixed the problem.

[image]

Comment: [`GtkScale`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html)?

Comment: Yep, that is a GtkScale widget.

Comment: Yes it is the GtkScael widget,found it and fixed the problem. Thank you. Some one write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the widget is "GtkScale".